# PowerShell -WebClient DownloadFile Wildcards?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, powershell, webclient

I want to copy multiple files from a SharePoint libary to a local directory.
It is possible to use Wildcards?
The following code is not working. But is there a way to use the WebClient and Wildcards?
(I must use the WebClient. It is not possible to use the SharePoint WebServices :-( )

```
$url = "http://mySharePoint/websites/Site/TestDocBib/*.jpg"
$path = "D:\temp\"

$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$WebClient.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
$WebClient.DownloadFile($url, $path)
```

Comment: Are the files in a list? you could get that, parse through it and then download the files individually...

Comment: Yes the files are in a list. But how it is possible to parse thrue the list? It is not possible to use the SharePoint WebService.

Comment: Why isn't it possible to use the Web Services?  The canonical answer would be to call the List web services' GetListItems method which would give you the URLs to the items in the document library.  Then you could use them with the WebClient to download them.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I realized that the Web Services are the best way. Because there is no other clean way to get the file urls. I want to use the Web Services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can parse though the html of the list.

```
# dummy url - i've added allitems.aspx
$url = "http://mySharePoint/websites/Site/TestDocBib/allitems.aspx"
$path = "D:\temp\"
$dl_file = $path + "allitems.html"

$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$WebClient.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
$WebClient.DownloadFile($url, $dl_file)
```

once you've downloaded the file you can parse though the file - a quick google turned up that Lee Holmes had done most of it already:

http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2005/09/05/unit-testing-in-powershell-%E2%80%93-a-link-parser/

the main bit you want is the regex:

```
$regex = “<\s*a\s*[^>]*?href\s*=\s*[`"']*([^`"'>]+)[^>]*?>”
```

I very quick hack - that may (or may not) work... but the gist is there :)

```
$test = gc $dl_file

$t = [Regex]::Matches($test, $regex, "IgnoreCase")
$i = 0
foreach ($tt in $t) { 
    # this assumes absolute paths - you may need to add the hostname if the paths are relative
    $url = $tt.Groups[1].Value.Trim() 
    $WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    $WebClient.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
    $WebClient.DownloadFile($url, $($path + $i + ".jpg"))
    $i = $i + 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, sorry, you can't use wildcards with WebClient.  It's not part of HTTP.

Answer (score 2):

What about using WEBDAV?

```
c:\> copy \\my.sharepoint.site\sites\foo\doclib\*.jpg c:\temp\
```

If the client end (i.e. not sharepoint) is a server 2008+ platform, you'll need to add the "desktop experience" role and enable the "webclient" service. This is not the same thing as system.net.webclient; it's the HTTP/DAV network redirector service.

If you need to log in with different credentials, you can use this:

```
c:\> net use * "http://my.sharepoint.site/sites/foo/doclib" /user:foobar
mapped h: to ...
c:\> copy h:\*.jpg c:\temp
```

Hope this helps.